# Format printing html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print out part of a web page but I cannot format it using a css stylesheet.  Here is my code.

Javascript:

```
function print()
{
  var Print=$("#myTable").html();
  newWin= window.open();
  newWin.focus();
  newWin.document.write("<html><head><title>Print Report</title><link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='/timer/css/print.css' type='text/css'></head>");
  newWin.document.write("<body><h2>ENTERPRISE FILE SYSTEMS REPORT</h2>");
  newWin.document.write(Print);
  newWin.document.write("</body></html>");
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

where myTable is a table I want to print.  The css file, "print.css" will not format the page.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Using firebug (or whatever client side tool you prefer), what's the response for the fetch request on "/timer/css/print.css"?

Comment: What browser? Not all (older) browsers recognise the `media='print'` attribute.